# get textbox value of input

Tags: php

```
</td> 
  <input type="text" name="billing" placeholder="Bill No." style= "background-color:; height:35px; width:100px;font-size:25px; "/>
</td> 

<td style="width:100px; ">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> "style=" background-color:; height:40px; width:100px;font-size:25px; "/>
</td>
```

I can't find value of text box but checkbox can. How can I do it through php

Comment: If check box not Checked , Most Browser Don't Send it! check it by `if(isset($_GET['']))`

Comment: Where are you looking? it should be called `$_POST['billing']` or `$_GET['billing']` depending on how you are sending the form. Also as `name="checked_id[]"` is passing an array, should the billing also be an array?

Comment: What's your form's method? POST? GET?

Answer (score 0):

Replace: 
`<input type="text" name="billing"  placeholder="Bill No." style= "background-color:; height:35px; width:100px;font-size:25px; "  value="value textfield"/>`

php: 
`<?php $textfield = $_POST['billing']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to catch the value of billing input is by catching either $_POST['billong'] or $_GET['billing'], on the server inside PHP.